# Change URL On Canvas LMS (Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, canvas-lms

want to change url

From This -
https://localhost/login/canvas

To -
https://localhost/login/Something

Please tell me where or how i can change the URL, what file would i have to change?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at the config/routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

Change it in your **config/routes.rb** file
If you post the contents of the file, it will be easier to say.

Comment: Thank you!It's too long to reply , But i'm giving you root portion  -  get 'accounts/:account_id/theme-preview' => 'brand_configs#show'
  root to: 'users#user_dashboard', as: 'root', via: :get
  # backwards compatibility with the old /dashboard url

Comment: change the part **get 'login/canvas'** to **get 'login/something'**

Comment: 'get 'login/canvas' => 'login/canvas#new', as: :canvas_login
  post 'login/canvas' => 'login/canvas#create'
  # deprecated alias
  post 'login' => 'login/canvas#create'' - want to redirect to the same page, just want to change the url, what should i change here?

Comment: You can set path in route 
Like get 'login/canvas' => 'login/canvas#new', as: :canvas_login, path: "login/something"